# Setting UIAlertController to show only in a container view via Swift/Storyboard

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, uialertcontroller

Is it possible to call a `UIAlertController` only within a smaller context on an iPad screen (i.e. for an iPhone simulator)? I have a container view with a `UIViewController` and am using:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true  
alertController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext  
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and I've also tried setting the context from the storyboard - both work fine for a standard `UIViewController` but nothing stops `UIAlertController` taking over the whole screen. Any suggestions?